# How can I communicate with serial port in Firefox?

Tags: applet, serial-port, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have already developed a Chrome App and Extension to communicate with serial ports of a client using API from https://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial. 
Currently I do the same operation in Firefox through a Java applet.
Since support for Java applet will be deprecated soon, I would like to develop an addon for Firefox for this.

The real problem is that I can't find any documentations in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API for an API able to work like the Chrome serial.

Comment: You can use js-ctypes, but I don't know if it's going to be allowed in WebExtensions, nothing concrete announced - https://github.com/Noitidart/ostypes

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this as "Addon SDK" question, I will assume you're trying to develop an extension using the SDK. The way to do it there would be to have a binary that communicates with the serial port and use [system/child_process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process) to communicate with that binary from the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a look at [jUART](https://github.com/billhsu/jUART)? They support Chrome, Firefox and also plan an IE version. If *avaScript is not the right thing for you maybe you have a look at the firefox plugin implementation and get some inspiration how they did it...